# How to change the color of GeoJSON layer?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, style

I want to show my road network in red color. How can I change this default color of the road network. Where should I attach style property?

```js
var roadNetwork = new L.LayerGroup();
$.getJSON("{% url 'road_dataset' %}", function (data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.road_name);
        }
    });
    geojson.addTo(roadNetwork);
});
```

Comment: please you should have a look to the official doc of leaflet then if you still have problem precise your problem https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ and I don't understand why it's link to jquery

Comment: Yes i already check this documentation. But i have no idea where i can insert the style function in jquery. For showing the data from database in geodjango i used jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't use jquery for this, jquery is a library for interacting with the DOM. You just have to define a style object and attach it to your layer, as seen in the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/):

```
var roadNetwork = new L.LayerGroup();

var myStyle = { // Define your style object
    "color": "#ff0000"
};

$.getJSON("{% url 'road_dataset' %}", function (data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {

        style: myStyle, // Assign the style object to the "style" property of the layer

        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.road_name);
        }
    });
    geojson.addTo(roadNetwork);
});
```